# How to convert java file into apk run on Android

Tags: java, android, compilation, apk

I am beginner in java. I want to compile/convert (.java) file into an apk file run on android. I am using Intellij idea . And can i convert only .java file without any gui (example :- .xml , .javax , swing). i have only (.java) file. I searched a lot on google but couldn't find it. Please help me.

Comment: Once you compiled/converted the java file without any GUI (which I guess means it's not an android app) to an APK, and you install that APK on a phone, what do you expect to happen if it's not an android app?

Comment: While "native Android" _looks_ a lot like java - it actually isn't exactly. In other words: you cannot just compile any odd java source file to "apk".

Comment: I recommend using Android Studio and to learn the basics of Android app development. Knowing Java only doesn't make anything unless you know the Android freamwork.

Comment: @Eyosiyas I am use Android Studio but my laptop is slow so i can't work properly. so, i want to convert .java to apk like "pyinstaller" that's type of tools . and i am a python programmer. now i am using java for a best android app.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That's why I don't use GUI because I want to create a background processing app . So ,I don't need any GUI. And i need to a tools like "pyinstaller" . what can i do now. without Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You either must include your java file into an android project, or you install some app which let you run java file e. g. Java N-IDE - Android Builder - Java SE Compiler

Comment: No, i use IntelliJ IDEA .  i need to a tools like "pyinstaller" for .java file into a android apk and my app do't use any GUI. what can i do now without Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Well for this we need to download android studio and create a gui for it. Then only you can get a apk file..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).